# Problemas com instance list em Haskell

Tags: haskell

Tenho um  trabalho na facu e tenho este erro:

> 'decide' is not a (visible) method of class `Char'

para o código abaixo:

```
data Paridade = Par | Impar deriving Show

class ParImpar a where
    decide :: a -> Paridade

instance ParImpar a => (Char [a]) where
    decide [a]
        | length [a] mod 2 == 0 = Par
        | otherwise = Impar
```

Answer (score 2):

O problema é que você está tentando fazer uma instância de `Char`(?!) para `[a]`. O que você quer é uma instância de `ParImpar` para `[a]`:

```
instance ParImpar [a] where
    decide a
        | mod (length a) 2 == 0 = Par
        | otherwise             = Impar
```

`Char` é um tipo, não um typeclass.